# Open Graph Post an custom Action types using koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, koala

Currently,I'm currently using Koala 1.4.0 to do open graph.

I did create an 
action types : View 
Object types : Advertisement

What I'm currently wish to archieve is : 
When Click the View button on the page, on the facebook ticker,it will show ,a user is viewing a advertisement.

Error i get:

```
    HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: advertisement."}}
```

How I trying to do it:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@user.token)
graph.put_connections("#{@user.uid}", "namespace:View" , :object=>"#{url_for(@advertisement)}"
```

It is in my show controller. And in my show.html.erb , i did included all the meta data . I did a share to Facebook function using koala also,its work well and successffully get the meta data from my page and post it on Facebook.

Using rails 3.0.9.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Koala, but it seems like you should be using ':advertisement' in place of ':object' in your graph.put_connections call. Example:

```
graph.put_connections("#{@user.uid}", "namespace:View" , :advertisement=>"#{url_for(@advertisement)}"
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I did tried your method and it gave me different error.

> Koala::Facebook::APIError (HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Could not retrieve data from URL

in my show there,i did include meta for it, I manage to share by getting meta data from my page,and its successful. So im have no idea why it cant retrieve data from the same URL

Comment: The error is telling you that Facebook couldn't get the appropriate info from the URL you provided. Try using the debug tool to check what Facebook sees when you publish an action against a URL. See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: yupz,i did use that debug tool. thanks ur info too. However, facebook mention about this thing for me
> Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
>Missing Required Property: The 'og:url' property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The 'og:title' property is required, but not present.

hmm,i got those things in my webpage, but i dono why it cannot retrieve from there and give me an error @@ izit my koala did wrong?

i did try for the full path of the specific url. It dint work

Comment: Can you share the URL you're using?

Comment: sorry,guy,are you aware what im posting on? @@

Comment: That URL doesn't load for me. Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`@graph.put_connections("me", "namespace:action", :object => object_url)`

Comment: hi bro, what it mean by :object => object_url ??? what should i put? because im getting error if im putting :object

Comment: When you create your action you typically define a 'Connected Object Type' like a Facebook profile, page, your own object, or whatever you like. These objects all have URLs. So if your action is on someone's profile, you would have something like:

@graph.put_connections("me", "my_company:some_action", :profile => 'https://www.facebook.com/someuser')

Comment: i will get back to u after try it,thanks for reply !! but what i do is
    graph.put_connections("#{@user.uid}", "friendadvert:View" , :advertisement=>"#{url_for(@advertisement)}"

i did created my new action and object type,and did include in my website,how come its not working?